# How to download android studio offline sdk without waiting sdk manager to download it?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I made a format for my laptop every 2 months, & my big problem I face is when Downloading and installing android studio sdk.. :(
It took long hours to download, and any interruption in connection, it will give error and restart from beginning..
Please any recommendations or help..

I've tried to install the android studio offline exe

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, until I came across this solution of offline sdk in one file. Please check this youtube video to get more info:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3k_sScH8_6U

Tell me if you solve the problem